# Converting ints to strs using Python

Tags: python, typeerror

I'm having a bit of issue when I execute some code that I wrote.

```
import requests
import time
import datetime
import os



def datarequest():
url = 'http://csgoroll.com/v1/roulette/state?token=bcb78foobar7b9'  # Could add a + pls str(pagesomething) to add on to the url so that it would update
sourcecode = requests.get(url)  # requests the data from the site
obj = sourcecode.json()
###

str1 = ''.join(str(e) for e in obj['rolls'])
for obj['roll'] in str1:

    rolldata = obj['roll'] in str1
    file = open("newfile.txt", "w")
    file.write(rolldata)
    file.close()
    file = open('newfile.txt', 'r')
    print(file.read())


###


if __name__ == '__main__':
while True:
    datarequest()
    time.sleep(120)  # these are seconds
```

Whenever I run this I got the error "TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bool" yet I am converting it to a string using the join statement, and I do not see where I put a bool statement anywhere.

If anyone could give me guidance on how to convert to the string properly from and int to solve my problem, I would appreciate it greatly, along with any general advice as to why I am having this issue within my program.

Comment: Please give us the full error, ideally including the stacktrace.

Comment: rolldata = obj['roll'] in str1 is a bool.

Comment: Side note, I'm pretty sure `for obj['roll'] in str1:` isn't what you want to do, given that you're iterating over a string...

Comment: @Iluvatar that replaces whatever values is at `obj['roll']` each pass of the loop. I didn't even know that behavior was legal, but I suppose it makes sense that it is. First time seeing that for me.

Comment: Sure, but it replaces it with a single character from the string. If you're writing out the whole string anyway, just do it in one go. You also never close the file after opening the second time.

Answer (score 1):

You write `rolldata` in this line:

```
file.write(rolldata)
```

but you set it to a boolean in this line:

```
rolldata = obj['roll'] in str1
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you could just go over it to find out why this is happening. You could simply try to debug it, go through everything carefully and make sure everything works. With problems I encounter like that, I like to add excessive things to it, and then slowly whittle it down to where it works.

So, to sum it up, in your case, just to make sure, simply try `str()` to start with, and continue debugging from there.

Answer (score 0):

```
rolldata = obj['roll'] in str1
```

this will return a bool and assign to 'rolldata'